# Visual Basic, problems filling an arraylist

Tags: arrays, vb.net, arraylist

I think I'm doing something weird here or maybe I'm just not well enough informed but I'm stuck at filling my arraylist with another array (size 2).

I originally program in Java and I thought this would work in Visual Basic but I can not find a solution. So here I am!

The problem at hand:
I've got two 2D arrays and I need to take the average for each part in the array. 
I loop through both of the array and perform some (easy) math. However, when it ends I get an array filled with the answer of the last made calculation.

What am I doing wrong here?
I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013

Here is the code that provides the combining of the two arrays:

```
Private Sub btnCombine_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCombine.Click
    'A safety to assure that the for loop will loop until the length of the 
    smallest array 
    If (dScanListMusic1.Count < dScanListMusic2.Count) Then
        combineCounter = dScanListMusic1.Count
    Else
        combineCounter = dScanListMusic2.Count
    End If

    For i As Integer = 0 To combineCounter - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To 1
            'Taking the average of the two doubles
            joinedAverage = (dScanListMusic1(i)(j) + dScanListMusic2(i)(j)) / 2
            dScanListMusicCombinedRow(j) = joinedAverage
        Next
        dScanListMusicCombined.Add(dScanListMusicCombinedRow)
    Next
```

Comment: This is by design, you fill the list with the same object repeatedly.  So all elements of the list have the same value.  You'll have to understand the difference between value types and reference types to see why.  Solve it by creating a *New* list inside the i loop.

Comment: Oh wow, I knew it was something that simple! Thanks!! Solved :)